# Absolute positioned element not extending with scrollable content (past 100%)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup window in which an element called `fade` is supposed to extend to the full width of the screen (it does this when there is no scrollable content). However when content exceeds 100% of the browser window it does not extend to 100% of the page height.

If i set `html, body { height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden; }` I get the result I want but then I get 2 scrollbars on the right hand side.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/Dpqg5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="fade"></div>
<div id="popup"></div>
<span id="open">Open Box</span>
```

**CSS**

```
#fade { display:none;width: 100%; min-height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;}
#popup { width: 200px; height: 300px; background-color: #ccc; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 50%; margin-left: -100px;display:none; }
#open { cursor: pointer; }
```

Any ideas on how to get this element to extend fully to the height of the web browser even when there is more scrollable content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your fade css to:

```
#fade { 
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```